# How do I write .txt files into python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

```
Name 1
car/machines
taxi
motorcycle

Name 2
address
phone number
age
education, school

Name 3
datetime
favorite
```

I would like to create a dictionary to save the name as the key and details under the name as values.
Example output:

```
{'Name 1': ['car/machines', 'taxi', 'motorcycle'], 'Name 2': ['address', 'phone number', 'age', 'education, school'] 'Name 3': ['datetime', 'favorite']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works although being a little bulky, maybe you could find a better solution but this one is quite fast.

```
#Reading the text file
text = open('text.txt', 'r')
#Turning it into a list of lines
lines = text.readlines()
#Defining the last name variable
#For later use
last_name = str()
#Defining the dict
lines_dict = dict()
#The +1 is there because i need to append the list to the key
#At the last iteration
for x in range(len(lines)+1):
    #The try is here because it will overflow
    try:
        #Stripping the line of the newline character
        lines[x] = lines[x].strip()
        #Check if the 'Name' string is in the line in question
        if 'Name' in lines[x]:
            #If there is any last name
            if 'Name' in last_name:
                #Filter the dictionary of empty spaces
                temp_list = list(filter(None, temp_list))
                #Appends the value to the key in the dict
                lines_dict[last_name] = temp_list
            #Getting the last name
            last_name = lines[x]
            #Resseting the temp list
            temp_list = list()
        #If the string is not 'Name'
        else:
            #Append the string to the temp list
            temp_list.append(lines[x])
    #If it overflows
    except Exception as e:
        #Do the last appending
        lines_dict[last_name] = temp_list
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think the caption names don't literally contain the string "Name", I think OP just wants to take the first line after an empty line as caption.

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for s in f.read().split('\n\n'):
        lines = s.split('\n')
        d[lines[0]] = lines[1:]
print(d)
```

This assumes there is no newline at the of your data file.

Comment: Thank you very much! If there is a newline at the end of the file, how to I prevent it from appending it as a value to the last key?

Comment: Many ways, you could either do `s.strip().split('\n')` (line 4) or `[line for line in lines[1:] if line]` (line 5)